# Displaying records from database which are equal to logged on user

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

I have created an MVC3 application which needs to show user specific data. The problem I am having is trying to display records which are equal to @user.Identity.Name.

The following Linq to SQL has been used to try to accomplish this:

```
        public ActionResult Index()
    {

        using (var db = new mydatEntities())
        {
            var details = from t in db.testadtas
                          where t.UserID ==  Viewbag.UsersRecord 
             select t; 

            return View();
        }

    }
```

(Update)

New to c# and Linq and finding it hard to write a query which will only display the logged on users records.

I have used the code below

```
 MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser  (User.Identity.Name, true /*   userIsOnline */);

Viewbag.UsersRecord = currentUser.ProviderUserKey;
```

I have then input the Viewbag.UserRecord into a textbox which updates a database field with the UserID in a table I have created.

I now want to write a linq query to say if UserID = Viewbag.UserRecord then show record with the UserID only

Is this a correct method to use for showing logged on user records?

or is there any other way which I can implement this in MVC3?

Answer (score 0):

Just use `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name`

Comment: any more information on HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name

Comment: The only thing you are trying to do is get the currently logged in user's name, correct?  In your controller you have access to HttpContext.User.Identity.Name which will contain the username they used to log in to your site.